# Retrieving saved draft of question

Tags: support, editor, drafts

I spent a fair amount of time putting in a question. As I did, I noticed a message saying a draft was saved. When I tried to post my question, it was unsuccessful - probably because I clicked on the post question button twice. Is there any to retrieve the saved draft from the previous question I tried to post? I'm way too tired to try and type it back in again.

Note: I tried to post this question in the meta superuser forum, but it said "You must have at least 5 reputation on Super User to ask a question."

Answer (score 3):

Now that you've created another question - I'm afraid there's no way to retrieve the other draft.

Comment: Does this apply across SE or per-site? That is, if you start a question/answer on SO, then start one on SU, will each have a separate draft?

Comment: @Synetech each site does have a separate draft

Comment: That’s what I figured. It’s just that the (long and comprehensive) edit I made to an answer yesterday seems to have vanished into thin air, so I was hoping the draft was still there, but nope; it’s gone. `:-(`